# How does predict_proba() function work internally?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, random-forest, knn

Can anyone help me understand the intuition and math behind predict_proba() in KNN algorithm with help of an example?

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/27444/how-does-sklearn-kneighborsclassifier-compute-class-probabilites

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is already answered in another SO : https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/27444/how-does-sklearn-kneighborsclassifier-compute-class-probabilites

Comment: Is the tags correct? I am confused about the `random-forest` tag